# After clicking OK button, Data should send to another window

Tags: java, adempiere

After clicking the OK button in the Window, It open the another window after clicking that Ok button. and I want to send the information into that window.

```
public void saveSelection(IMiniTable miniTable) {

    final int AD_Window_ID = 1000108;

    String whereString = " ROUTE_ID" + getM_Route_ID();

    final AWindow poFrame = new AWindow();

    final MQuery query = new MQuery("ROUTE_ID");

    query.addRestriction(whereString);

    final boolean ok = poFrame.initWindow(AD_Window_ID, query);

    if (!ok) {
        return;
    }``

    poFrame.pack();

    AEnv.showCenterScreen(poFrame);

    return;

}
```

help me out

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Please read the [help] pages to see what sort of question are allowed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are manipulating window inside adempiere , you can get the ad_window_id from context like #AD_Window_ID.
When you inicialize another windows, you can get this object to add logs or info to show inside frame.